# Book: boyfriend travels to alternate dimension to save kidnapped girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, books

2009 or earlier. I think he recruits orcs to save her, and it might have been a series. There might be a character named Mrs.Stoner. It was in English. I think the cover was green.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question could use some more details.  You should check out [how to ask a story-identification question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some ideas of other things to add.